# java.lang.NullPointerException XML tag

Tags: java, xml, null

I have an xml document that has (I think) a little bit strange structure that hassles me a bit. It looks like the following:

```
<Test1>84.23</Test1>
<Test2>2014-12-01</Test2>
<Test3></Test3>
<Test4>Green</Test4>
<Test5>Bottle</Test5>
<Test6/>
<Test7/>
```

The problem is the structure for the tag `<Test3></Test3>`, as you can se the other tags - when empty - delivers just e.g. `<Test6/>`

For the "normal" tags (e.g. `<Test6/>`) I can use the following code to check if it is empty, null or returning 0.

```
if(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Test6").item(0).getTextContent().isEmpty() 
                    || eElement.getElementsByTagName("Test6").item(0).getTextContent().trim().length() == 0
                    || eElement.getElementsByTagName("Test6").item(0).getTextContent() == null)        
                    {
                        array[1] = null;
                    }
```

But when applying the above code on the `<Test3></Test3>`-tag structure I always get `java.lang.NullPointerException`

I have also tried applying `"".equals(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Test6").item(0).getTextContent())` in my if statement but still get the null exception thrown.

All I want to do is to set the array[1] to null if the Test3 -tag is empty, 0 or null. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I expect that the call to `getElementsByTagName("Test6")` returns an empty `NodeList`.  If you call `item(...)` on an empty `NodeList`, it is going to return `null`, no matter what the index is.  You then try to call methods on that `null`, and that gives you an NPE.

> What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

You need to test the `NodeList` size before you attempt to index it.  Or test for the `null`.

Hint: read the javadocs!